# Can a javascript program read the validation result given by `type="email"` of `input` element?

Tags: javascript, html

in HTML, `type="email"` of `input` element  can validate if an input string has a valid email format.

I would like to write a javascript program which will act differently when an input string to such an `input` element has or doesn't have a valid email format.

Can a javascript program read  the validation result given by `type="email"` of `input` element? If not, why?

Or do I have to implement validation of email format in Javascript instead?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Validation

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :invalid pseudoselector and querySelectorAll. In the following two email inputs - one with an invalid value set and one with a valid email. Css styling (using the :invalid pseudoselector to indicate which one is which. The console log will query all inputs that are invalid and log them.

The bigger issue may be the validation that is required to pass may be as simple as requiring a "@" symbol - so this is not a very stringent validation.

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('input:invalid');
console.log(test);
```

```css
input:invalid{background: red}
```

```html
<input type="email" value="blah.com"/>
<input type="email" value="blah@blah.com"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem you can do something like this

```
<form id='form' action='post'>
    <input id='email' type='email' required/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>

<script>
    console.log( document.getElementById('form').checkValidity() );
    console.log( document.getElementById('email').checkValidity() );
</script>
```